# How can I propagate raspberry plants from cuttings?

Tags: propagation, cuttings, raspberries

A few years ago I purchased five raspberry plants and since then all but one of them have died. I would like to take as many cuttings as I can from this plant and root them to replace what I've lost. What are the steps to take in order to do this?

Comment: If raspberries are dying... Solve that first, the raspberries will spread rapidly if they are doing well... Even if it is possible to root raspberries, people typically don't as they spread by rhizome so quickly.

Comment: I agree with Grady - I have never seen or heard of anyone propagating by cuttings - they spread themselves.  And to it amazingly well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am trying to do clone cuttings now too using rooting hormone.  I've ran across some people saying they did it, but now how they did it.  You can find out more on Tipping ( bending the plant over and putting the tip in the dirt until it grows) and air layering.  Have yo had any success yet?  I'll let you know if I get mine to grow.